# Cannot extend WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter in Spring Boot 1.4

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'd like to update a web project to Spring Boot 1.4 but I'm getting and error.

I'm currently using Spring Boot 1.3.3 and I'm extending `WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter` to map some custom resource hanlders:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/users/**").addResourceLocations("http://file-storage/images/users/");
        // ...

}
```

I noticed that in the new version of SB a constructor was added to `WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter`:

```
public WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter(ResourceProperties resourceProperties,
        WebMvcProperties mvcProperties, ListableBeanFactory beanFactory,
        HttpMessageConverters messageConverters,
        ObjectProvider<ResourceHandlerRegistrationCustomizer> resourceHandlerRegistrationCustomizerProvider) {}
```

and this constructor uses `ResourceHandlerRegistrationCustomizer` that is a package-protected interface, so, basically, from version 1.4 is not possible to extend autoconfiguration.

What is an alternative way to extend autoconfiguration?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's no need to extend `WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter` to add some custom resource handlers (and never has been). You should extend Spring MVC's [`WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.html) instead.

Comment: Hm, I actually think there's a need: When you only want to add additional ResourceResolvers to a chain, which is not possible right now.